# Mouse position is only read on the first frame

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

i have been having trouble with reading a mouse position on a canvas. The code is working (semi) correctly as it reads the position when clicking he canvas in IE but only on one frame, in chrome it is just displaying the value as 0.

Here is the full code:

```
    <script>
        var blip = new Audio("blip.mp3");
        blip.load();

        var levelUp = new Audio("levelUp.mp3");
        levelUp.load();

        var canvas = document.getElementById('game');
        var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
        context.font = '18pt Calibri';
        context.fillStyle = 'white';

        //load and draw background image
        var bgReady = false;
        var background = new Image();
        background.src = 'images/background.jpg';
        background.onload = function(){
            bgReady = true;
        }

        var startMessage = 'Click the canvas to start';

        //load plane image
        var planeReady = false;
        var planeImage = new Image();
        planeImage.src = 'images/plane.png';
        planeImage.onload = function() {
            planeReady = true;
        }

        //load missile image
        var missileReady = false;
        var missileImage = new Image();
        missileImage.src = 'images/missile-flipped.gif';
        missileImage.onload = function() {
            missileReady = true;
        }

        //initialise lives and score
        var score = 0;
        var lives = 3;
        var missilesLaunched = 0;
        var missileSpeed = 5;
        var level = 1;

        var missileX = 960;
        var missileY = Math.random() * 500;
        if (missileY > 480) {
            missileY = 480;
        }

        function getMousePos(canvas, event) {
            return {
                x: input.x - rect.left,
                y: input.y - rect.top
            };
        }

        function update_images(event) {
            var pos = getMousePos(canvas.getBoundingClientRect(), mouseInput);
            planeImage.y = pos.y;

            missileX = missileX - missileSpeed;

            if (missileX < - 70) {
                missilesLaunched++;
                missileX = 960;

                missileY = Math.random() * 500;
                if (missileY > 480) {
                    missileY = 480;
                }

                blip.play();
                score = missilesLaunched;

                if (score % 5 == 0) {
                    missileSpeed = missileSpeed + 2;
                    level++;
                    levelUp.play();
                }

            }
        }



        function reload_images() {

            if (bgReady = true) {
                context.drawImage(background, 0, 0);
            }

            if (planeReady = true) {
                context.drawImage(planeImage, 10, planeImage.y);
            }

            if (missileReady = true) {
                context.drawImage(missileImage, missileX, missileY);
            }



            context.fillText('Lives: ' + lives, 200, 30);
            context.fillText('Score: ' + score, 650, 30);
            context.fillText('Level: ' + missileSpeed, 420, 30);
            context.fillText('Position: ' + missileImage.y, 420, 70);
        }

        function main(event) {

            var mouseInput = { x: 0, y: 0 };

            document.addEventListener("mousemove", function (event) {
            mouseInput.x = event.clientX;
            mouseInput.y = event.clientY;
            });

            update_images(event);
            reload_images();

            if (lives > 0) {
                window.requestAnimationFrame(main);
            }
            else {

            }
        }

        function start() {

            context.drawImage(background, 0, 0);
            context.fillText('Click the canvas to start', 350, 250);

            function startMain(event) {
                game.removeEventListener("click", startMain);
                main(event);
            }

            canvas.addEventListener("mousedown", startMain);
        }

        start();

    </script>
```

Comment: if u give me as fiddle code, i can easily find out.

Comment: Here you go https://jsfiddle.net/sLx9L3nu/

Comment: Every time you click on the canvas, an additional instance of the game loop is starting... :)

Comment: Thanks for the reply Chris, how could this be fixed then? I'm relatively new to the html5 canvas.

Comment: I think Norguard gave a good answer to help you out.

Answer (score 2):

Joe, you should actually be capturing the mouse position every time you click...

...but you're actually also starting a new game (without stopping the old one), every time you click, too.

First problem: *starting game engine several times to draw on the same instance of the canvas*

Solution:

In your `start` function, you need to remove the `mousedown` event listener, after you've triggered it.

```
function start () {
    // ... other setup
    function startMain (event) {
        canvas.removeEventListener("click", startMain);
        main(event);
    }
    canvas.addEventListener("click", startMain);
}
```

Now it will only listen for the first click, before starting, and will only start once.

Second Problem: *mouse doesn't update as expected*

Solution: two issues here...
...first, you are passing `event` into `main` on first call...
...after that, you're passing `main` into `requestAnimationFrame`.

`requestAnimationFrame` won't call it with an event, it will call it with the number of microseconds (or ms or some other unit as a fractional precision of ms) since the page was loaded.

So the first time you got `main({ type: "mousedown", ... });`.
The next time you get `main(4378.002358007);`

So lets refactor the `startMain` we had above, so that `main` never ever collects an event, just a time.

```
function startMain ( ) {
  canvas.removeEventListener("click", startMain);
  requestAnimationFrame(main);
}
```

The next problem is that even if you were getting just events, you're only ever capturing a click event (which as we mentioned earlier, fires a new copy of the game logic).

Your solution is to separate the code which catches mouse events from the code which reads mouse position.

```
var mouseInput = { x: 0, y: 0 };

document.addEventListener("mousemove", function (event) {
  mouseInput.x = event.clientX;
  mouseInput.y = event.clientY;
});


function getMousePos (rect, input) {
  return {
    x : input.x - rect.left,
    y : input.y - rect.top
  };
}


// currently in updateImages (should not be there, but... a different story)
var pos = getMousePos(canvas.getBoundingClientRect(), mouseInput);
```

You've got other problems, too...
You're calling `getMousePos` and passing in `game` at the moment. I don't see where `game` is defined in your JS, so either you're making `game` somewhere else (begging for bugs), ***or it's `undefined`, and your app blows up right there***.

You should really be building this with your console / dev-tools open, in a hands-on fashion, and cleaning bugs in each section, as you go.

Comment: Thanks for the lengthy reply, I have tried to implement this into the code but may have made a few errors. I have updated the code above.

Comment: @JoeEaston; that's a start, but you should slow down on adding new functionality until you have your bugs worked out, at very least. Right now, your game isn't even going to load. You've got `game.removeEventListener` et cetera in your code, and I still don't see a `game` variable, which would mean that this would crash right there. Did you mean `canvas`? Next, the inside of `getMousePos` has been rewritten, but the actual function arguments still expect `(canvas, event)` not `(rect, input)`. That will blow up. Next, `mouseInput` and the `"mousemove"` listener can't be inside `main`

Comment: They have to be global (as far as your current game structure goes). `main` gets called 60 times per second. You don't want to add another listener 60 times a second. You want to add one listener to the whole page, and have it update one `mouseInput` object for the whole page (again, as far as your structure goes). Also, you're still passing `main(event)` on your first call. This stuff has to be refactored or its going to keep you from getting it up and running (and being fun). Keep your console open and read through the errors in order.

Comment: Thanks for your help! The problem was that `pos` wasn't declared globally amongst various other things (as you well know).